# Managing multiple NSArrays on a different UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, nsarray

is it possible to manage multiple **NSArrays** on a different **View Controller**?

Here's my example:

I am currently working with **two View Controllers**:

**TableViewController** serves as a main menu.  I've set up multiple **UIButtons**, each has a tag and when the user presses a button, it'll take them to the **TableOneViewController**.

In **TableOneViewController**, so far I've set up an **UIImageView** and a **UIButton**, every time the user presses the button, the **UIImageView** changes the image through an **NSArray**.

I want to use the **tags** on the **TableViewController** to manage the **NSArrays** of the **TableOneViewController**.  Is this possible?  So far, my code is not working.

Here's the code. Thanks!

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)tableSelection:(id)sender
{

    TableOneViewController *TOVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableOneViewController"];


    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:TOVC.numOne forKey:@"num"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1.png" forKey:@"num2"];

    }


    if ([sender tag] == 2) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:TOVC.numTwo forKey:@"num"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"2.png" forKey:@"num2"];

    }

    if ([sender tag] == 3) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:TOVC.numThree forKey:@"num"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"3.png" forKey:@"num2"];

    }


    [self presentViewController:TOVC animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

**TableOneViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    int index = tableCounter++ % [self.numOne count];
    self.num.image = self.numOne[index];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.num.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"num"]];
    self.num2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"num2"]];




    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableCounter = 10;

    self.numOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                   nil];

    self.numTwo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"20.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"30.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"40.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"50.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"60.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"70.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"80.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"90.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"100.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                   nil];

    self.numThree = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"200.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"400.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"500.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"600.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"700.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"800.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"900.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1000.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"100.png"],
                   nil];
}
```

Comment: It's just data.  View controllers are just objects.  If you have the address of an array you can manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the array before presenting the view controller (`viewDidLoad` hasn't be called yet), then you present it, but you initialize `numOne` (and the other arrays) in `viewDidLoad`. I suggest to use lazy initialization, here's the example for `numOne`, write the same for the other two arrays:

```
- (NSArray*) numOne
{
    if(!_numOne)
    {
       _numOne= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                   nil];
    }
    return _numOne;
}
```

However this is not the purpose of `NSUserDefaults`, I consider this approach bad design. It's better if you keep an ivar in `TableOneViewController` that points to one of the three arrays (same for the image name).

**Edit**

This is how I would implement the mechanism: an additional property that points to one of the three arrays in `TableOneViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray* currentArray;
```

This pointer should point to the correct array, according to the tag of the sender that triggered `tableSelection:` :

```
// TableViewController
- (IBAction)tableSelection:(id)sender
{

    TableOneViewController *TOVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableOneViewController"];
    switch([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            TOVC.currentArray= TOVC.numOne;
            break;
        case 2:
            TOVC.currentArray= TOVC.numTwo;
            break;
        case 3:
            TOVC.currentArray= TOVC.numThree;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    [self presentViewController:TOVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// TableOneViewController
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    int index = tableCounter++ % [self.currentArray count];
    self.num.image = self.currentArray[index];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I make the **NSArray** work with the `([sender tag] == )` in the **TableViewController**?

Comment: You can leave it as it is, and just add the lazy initialization of the array properties if you still want to use NSUserDefaults. If instead you want to follow the other approach, according to the tag you assign the view controller's array (e.g.: tag=1, then you assign it to numOne).

Comment: I've added the lazy initialization and I'm still having problems with the `- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender` button. It only throws one NSArray for all tags. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You've written self.num.image = self.numOne[index]; then only the elements of numOne are being picked, do you want to pick also elements from numTwo and numThree?

Comment: Correct, I want to pick the elements of numTwo and numThree too, according to the 3 tags set in the _TableViewController.m_. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Ramy! I was going back and forth with the tag setup, but your method worked flawlessly!

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't work because

`TableOneViewController *TOVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableOneViewController"];`

creates a completely new instance of your TableOneViewController. I would use a singleton retaining the arrays and any other info I need as a single access point during the execution of my program.

Comment: I would advise against using a singleton, it would be better to pass the array items to the controller.

Comment: Agree if he is going to use the array just in those two view controllers